# Stop Chrome from reloading tabs

Tags: google-chrome, hibernate, browser-tabs

Recently Chrome updated and since then every time I switch between tabs I have to wait for the activated tab to refresh. Is there a way to tell Chrome to quit hibernating inactive tabs?

Comment: see chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From information written on Chromium OS site (which applies to the Chrome browser as well) [here](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/tab-discarding-and-reloading), it says that the tabs are getting "hibernated" because your device is getting low on memory.

It suggests that you: 
`"Close some tabs or uninstall extensions that take a lot of memory. If there's a specific tab you don't want discarded, right-click on the tab and pin it."`

Also, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding-in-chrome-46) second article, experimental version of Chrome (Chrome 46 Canary build, at the time of writing this answer) will implement a feature called **Tab Discarding**, which will preserve the state of the tabs that will be discarded.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Any idea how to turn it off? It brakes the sense of using tabs...

Comment: @SledgehammerPL: Your best try will be to raise your page file size.

Comment: Chromium OS info doesn't always apply to Chrome on other OSs: `Why doesn't Chrome do this on Mac / Windows / Goobuntu?
Those machines swap memory out to disk when they get low on resources. Changing tabs then slows down as the data is loaded from disk.`

Comment: This feature is totally broken. Until it was added, I never had a single instance of memory overload. Right now, I have more than 1 GB of free RAM but Chrome has discarded 15 of my open tabs. I have a slow CPU, so clicking on a discarded tab takes 10-15 seconds each time. It's a good idea really, but way too aggressive. Interestingly, Google tells us the exact opposite on Android, unused memory is useless memory so nothing is discarded until it fills up.

Comment: @SledgehammerPL to turn it off use chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

Answer (score 25):

What helped as a general solution for all tabs for me:

*you can turn this off by going to "chrome://flags/" and selecting "Disabled" under "Enable tab discarding "*

(taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3kg79l/chrome_keeps_refreshing_every_page_and_its/d0dtcqx)

Answer (score 0):

above answers are not working anymore, use this extension instead.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.