# Stop Chrome from refreshing tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

Ever since an update or two ago (I am currently at Chrome OS 51), changing the value of `#memory-pressure-thresholds` to `Conservative memory pressure release strategy` doesn't prevent tabs from being refreshed by Chrome (I was never told what value to set it to, so that one sounded right). There is also NO `#discard-tabs` option like some people have been suggesting. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: In what circumstances is Chrome refreshing tabs? What is the ultimate problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/970244/152004

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Chrome from reloading tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/970244/stop-chrome-from-reloading-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

To see the 'Discarded Tabs', type this in the Address Bar: chrome://flags/

To actually disable:, type in your address bar:  chrome://flags, then disable this flag: Automatic-tab-discarding (Turn it to 'Disabled' from 'Default')