# How to stop Google Chrome from refreshing tabs that fail to load

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser-tabs

**Note:** This is *not* [memory pressure](https://superuser.com/questions/1094689/stop-chrome-from-refreshing-tabs) (I have 40GB of RAM on a 64-bit system) or tab discarding. Please read on for full details. Both flags also no longer exist and I cannot turn them off anyway. Installing [an extension that disables tab discarding](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok) does not do anything (because this isn't discarding).

---

When a tab *fails to load* (i.e. I am offline, the server is not running, some other network error), visiting that tab later causes Chrome to try to refresh it. Sometimes this will result in the same error, sometimes a different error, and sometimes the error will disappear and be replace by a working website.

Whatever the case is, I do *not* like having Chrome automate these actions for me. Even if a tab failed to load and is showing an error, I would not like it to be refreshed automatically even if I click on the tab.

I have checked and there do not seem to be any flags under the traditional search terms. Searching "refresh", "auto", "error", and so on doesn't reveal anything. How do I disable this auto-refresh?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Chrome from reloading tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/970244/stop-chrome-from-reloading-tabs)

Comment: @Anonymous Unfortunately not, as stated at the top of the question this is not tab hibernation or discarding, this is Chrome auto-refreshing tabs that failed to load.