# Stop Chrome from unloading pinned tabs

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

While most issues people have seem to be with Chrome loading unwanted unpinned tabs, I want Chrome NOT to discard pinned tabs.

As [linked](https://superuser.com/questions/970244/stop-chrome-from-reloading-tabs) , the [Chromium page](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/tab-discarding-and-reloading) statement "If there's a specific tab you don't want discarded, right-click on the tab and pin it." just does not seem to be true, in the sense, it DOES get discarded eventually when the going gets tough, as mentioned in the same page.

My question is - is there any way to prevent this, it does not even reload when memory is finally available, have to do it manually by selecting it.

I pin tabs like my notes keeper, reminder service & hangouts (for SMS) so I can get notifications in real time.

Answer (score 1):

[The Great Discarder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-discarder/jlipbpadkjcklpeiajndiijbeieicbdh) browser extension prevents discarding of pinned tabs by default and also allows to whitelist URLs without pinning them. Also check [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) if you need more control over tab discarding.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAmIS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand on that? Please have a read of [how to recommend software in an answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) :)

Comment: I checked those out - didnt make a diff -  then moved onto Vivaldi that does exactly what I expect and is much less evil.